# Comparing Cells in a variable number of Columns

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

So I've been asked to compare data in a chart where the number of columns can be variable, currently up to 20, But I'm told that could change so I'd like to leave that as dynamic as possible.

The goal is to make sure that all of the cells in a row contain the exact same strings, or are blank. So if there are five columns, three have the data "Good" and the other two are blank, that would be fine.

The chart will always start in the upper left corner and always have both header rows and Row names.

I thought I would compare each cell to the first cell in each row, but I can't seem to figure out how to compare variable cells.

I am pretty new to using VBA and am entirely self taught, so I may be on the wrong track here.

Here's my sample code, I know I'll need to do a couple of Do Loops to get this working, but I Wanted to get this part working first.

```
Sub Row_Checker()

    Dim Col_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer


    Range("a1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select


    Col_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection)


    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Range("A1").Select

    For I = 2 To Col_Count
        If ("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = ("B" & (ActiveCell.Row).Offset(0, I) then


End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want it to do when there is a mismatch/what do you want it to do when all of the columns in the same row have a blank or are the same?

Comment: Also, you're starting in column 2 - do you want to ignore column A? And should each row be a certain value? Like the value in `A1` should be the same as all the other values in row 1? Or can they all be a random value, just have to be the same value each row?

Comment: Also, is row one a header row without blanks?  If not, your `col_count` variable could have the incorrect value if there are blanks in the first row. I assume it is since you start iterating on row 2, but just want to double check.

Comment: I Was hoping to just flag the rows, either by adding another column with some sort of tag or maybe just highlighting the given row so they can be reviewed. I was going to ignore column A because that will be the label for the row. They could be a different value PER row, but each row should have all the same value. Row 1 is a Haader row and it will not have blanks.

Comment: I'll update my answer to have it highlight rows that don't have a match.  Let me know if the answer below is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make a few recommendations for more efficient code.  I'll also help you out with writing the loop.

First of all, always avoid using `select` as much as possible.  It is inefficient and makes the code harder to read and more likely to break.  Here, instead of selecting, I put the value of the first column of the row in a variable called `val1` then I loop through the other columns putting their values in a variable called `valn`.

Since there could be missing data, I used the find function to find the lowest row that is populated and then assigned that to the variable `lRow`.

For the next part, you have to do a loop inside of a loop.  In your outer loop you will iterate through the rows, on the inner loop you will iterate through the columns.  So you will go to a row, loop through all of the columns and then go to the next row and do the same thing.

You can use `cells(I,J)` to move through different cells in your loop.  This is a powerful part of looping.

You can fill in what you want to happen if the cell values match or are blank and what you want it to do if they do not.

Also, be sure the change any `sheet1` to the actual sheet name you are working with.

See the below code:

```
Sub row_checker()

    Dim Col_Count As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim val1 As String
    Dim valn As String
    Dim output As String



    Col_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(1))

    lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

        For I = 2 To lRow
            For J = 2 To Col_Count
            val1 = Cells(I, 1).Value
            valn = Cells(I, J).Value
                If val1 = valn Or valn = Empty Then
                Else: Cells(I, J).Interior.Color = 65535
                End If
            Next J
        Next I

End Sub
```

Congratulations on being self-taught.  I'm also 100% self-taught in VBA and programming.  I'm no expert, but I have learned quite a few things along the way.  What I've shared are a few of the things it took me too long to learn.  Good luck and let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I wanted, Thanks for the advice!